# How to associate an event with the option id of a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to add a `div` element to a page after a particular option in the select box is selected. How can I do it using jQuery? I am trying to use the `onClick` event but it doesn't works.

```
<div class="col-xs-7">
    <label for="sel1">Filter Type:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option>Text</option>
        <option onclick="Adddivision();">List</option>  
    </select>
</div>
<script>
  function Adddivision(){

      <div class="col-xs-6">
      <label for="Filter Options">Filter Options:</label>
      </div>    
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Edward that is not JQuery, nor is it valid Javascript.

Comment: ya its just that i knew the answer will be given by jquery

Comment: If you don't want the answer to be jQuery than you should explicit write it in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('#sel1').on('change', function() {
  if($(this).find('option:selected').text()=="List" ){
     $('body').append('<div class="col-xs-6"><label for="Filter Options">Filter Options:</label></div>')//append div
     $('#sel1').off('change');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onchange jQuery event.

```
$(document).on("change", "#sel1", function(){
 if($(this).val() == 2) // 2 is the value of the <option> tag
 {
 var divElement = "<div>The Div Element that you want to be appended to your page</div>";
   $("body").append(divElement);
}
});
```

Comment: where option value 2 is specified? I think you can compare text of option instead.

Comment: What will you do, If your page is translated into other languages(ex.French).Will your code work? Whenever you use select use 'value' attribute of <option> tag. <select><option value="2">Text</option><option value="1">Option 1 Text</option></select>

Comment: Adding to that, integer comparison on is more faster than the one with string

Comment: thanks for the reply u guys have amazing coding skills

Answer (score 0):

You can use below jQuery to bind `change` event to select box and check if selected option is `List`, then append label to the div

```
$('#sel1').on('change', function() {
  var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  if(text =="List" );
   {
    $(".col-xs-6").append('<label for="Filter Options">Filter Options:</label>');
   }
});
```